# Can echo true but wont return

Tags: php

Im trying to return true when my loop has finished but it does not seem to happen.
I can get it to echo true or false or any text but returning does nothing.

Wonder if anyone could explain why this is.

Here is the (kinda) function I have removed the data base calls and such as its not important.

```
function loop_me(){
// this part is not important...
    $finished = false;
    $done  = 0;
    $userC = 1000;
    $page  = 0;
    $count = 10;
    $array = array()
    $data = array('1','2','3') // big array of data...

    if($done < $userC){

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $array[] = $data[$i];
    }


// bellow is the important part...      
    if($done >= $userC){
        $finished = true;
    }else{
       $page++;
       loop_me();
    }
}

if($finished){
// If I echo true it outputs 1 (this is fine)
// if I return true I get nothing this is got good as I want to do an IF statement on the 
// output, which I can't do if it does not.
    echo(true);
}
}
```

Ok so the function with the issue is above but just to help you out, the basic idea of the function is that i loops thought an array of data (not showen above) but this data is paginated so it needs to go to the next 'page' once its finished with the first and there a few pages so what I want to do is when it has finished looping thought it all return true.

Might be a simple fix.

But I can't work it out.

Comment: Is this being called via AJAX? This may explain why you see echo statements but not return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called 'loop_me()' recursively, but you need to return it.

```
}else{
   $page++;
   return loop_me();
}
```

and of course change echo to return too!

Comment: Not needed. He needs to return a value at the end of his function.
You don't use the `return` function for recursion.

Comment: No it worked, thanks @danf I did not think of that. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

edit your `echo (true);` to something like: `return true;`   then call your function:

```
$var = loop_me();
echo $var;    // If a success you should see true.
```

You should also consider adding a return false if there is a problem when calling your defined function.